# Windows Lost in Desktop Spaces – Seeking Solutions

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ventura

[image: Screenshot 1]

I have multiple Chrome windows open on my desktops 2 and 3. However, I often lose track of my windows. I tried clicking on Chrome in the Dock, hoping that macOS would bring the app to the foreground for me.

[image: Screenshot 2]

Currently, it doesn't work as expected.

Have I missed a setting somewhere?
Do you find this behavior annoying as well?
Has anyone found a solution to this issue?

[Link to Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhMQu.png)
[Link to Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6uaY.png)

---

Comment: It focuses the app when you click on the Dock icon.  But if you have windows belonging to the app on multiple desktops, how do you expect one of them to be brought to the foreground?  You don't detail your expectation.